# Meteor: Ionic serve on Windows vs OSx

Tags: ios, macos, meteor, ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2` and `Meteor`.  I built an app in `Windows` and it runs perfectly on an `Android` platform.

I now have `OSx` and am trying to build the app fro `iOS`. I have installed `npm`, `cordova` successfully.

And:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

But when I run:

```
ionic serve
```

I get no errors in the CLI, but when I try access the app in Firefox:

```
localhost:8100
```

The Firebug console reports the following error:

```
      Error: There is already a collection named "chats"
require<.node_modules.meteor.mongo["collection.js"]/Mongo.Collection
```

This error does not happen in an `Android/Windows` environment.

**Code**

```
chats.ts

  import { Chats, Messages } from 'api/collections';
  ...

  public chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat>;

collections.ts

  import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
  import {Chat, Message} from 'api/models';

  export const Chats: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>('chats');
  export const Messages: Mongo.Collection<Message> = new Mongo.Collection<Message>('messages');
```

Am I perhaps missing a step in the `iOS` environment?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I build the app on Windows, where it runs perfectly. Now I am trying to get it to run on OSx where I have the above problems. As you can see my versions are not exactly the same. I this maybe the problem?

Windows:

> ```
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
> OS:
> Node Version: v6.2.2
> ```

OSx:

> ```
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
> 6.4.0
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: OS X El Capitan
> Node Version: v6.9.1
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same project in IOS environment, you may need to delete the old transpiled js/.map files
Check this link: https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/318

Comment: thank you.  I am having a look at my app, and I am struggling to work out which files to delete. There are so many `*js.map` files. Also there are a lot of `collection.js.map` files. These files seem to be in various folders in `node_modules`. Which ones should I delete.

Comment: No. not the ones in node_modules. Those are dependencies that are installed on doing `npm install` . If you have deleted any, just remove the folder and do npm install on the project

Comment: If you have any compiled js/map in your src files delete those or www folder.

Comment: I delete all `*.js.map` files under `www`. When I run `ionic serve` it creates an `app.bundle.js.map` as expected. But I still get the `Error: There is already a collection named "chats"` error at `app.bundle.js:334:14943`.

Comment: In situations like this one thing that works is delete node_modules,delete www folder. Run npm install and then do ionic serve

Comment: sry I cudnt give more accurate ans

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. After installing `npm` and running `ionic serve`, I get: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardmarais/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/www/index.html'`

Comment: oh..It is refering to Windows path instead of Mac for some reason..do you have any custom config in package.json?

Comment: My `package.json` seems just to have the `dependencies`, `devDependencies`, `name`, `description` and `cordovaPlugins`. They just consist of names and version numbers.

Comment: I build the app on Windows, where it runs perfectly. Now I am trying to get it to run on OSx where I have the above problems. As you can see my versions are not exactly the same. I this maybe the problem?  I have added the versions above.

Comment: You could create a blank template of ionic 2 project . copy paste your src directory there and then add any additional package/plugin your app uses

Comment: I think that's good advise. I will try that tomorrow. Appreciate the help.