# Install Ionic 2 on OSX

Tags: macos, ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`, `npm 3.10.8` and `node 6.9.2 LTS`. The reason why I want to use this version, is because I have an existing Ionic app of this version built on Windows.

My problem is the following. I have installed `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` on OSX, but as soon as I try create a new app and `serve` the app, I get the following errors.

> `Couldn't find ionic.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?`

There is however an `ionic.config.json` file.

[image]

If anyone can please give me some advise how to run Ionic on OSX I would appreciate it. When I do the same on Windows, I don't seem to have any problems.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I downgraded to `node 6.2.2`, but as you can see, I still get the same error.

[image]

**UPDATE**

As you can see there is an `ionic.config.json` file. Should I rename it to `ionic.json`?

[image]

**UPDATE**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-app-base",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I rename the `ionic.config.json` file to `ionic.json`, `ionic serve` starts and tries to open the app in a browser, but gets the following error:

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
 '/Users/richardmarais/ionic-apps/theWhoZoo/www/index.html'
```

Comment: Can you mention the npm version?

Comment: does the app run with the latest ionic in OSX?

Comment: I did try the latest version of Ionic and it worked with a Vanilla app (`ionic start`) on OSX. But my existing app is `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`. I am reluctant to upgrade my existing Android app to the latest version because I am scared it breaks. However, because `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` doesn't seem to work on OSX, I may have to?

Comment: Do you suggest I upgrade my existing Android app to the latest version of Ionic?

Comment: I am not sure how to get the exact package.json for beta version. Clearly some of the packages in OSX have issues in your previous version. If you are able to make it work with the latest ionic in OSX I dont see an issue..

Comment: I haven't tried updating my existing app to the latest Ionic, but I can get a vanilla app to work on OSX with the latest version. I agree, I think OSX has problems with the old beta version.  I am going to try upgrade my existing Windows/Android app to the latest version of Ionic, and then try get it working on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

[Known Issue in beta](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/960)

You may  have to downgrade node version. maybe (6.2)

UPDATE:

```
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
```

Your project is in RC 3 not in Beta
You can install the latest ionic cli

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

and revert to latest npm

Comment: I downgraded to `node 6.2.2`. but still get the same error (see update above).

Comment: try an older version.

Comment: With `node 5.12.0`, I still get the same error. The thing is on Windows I am using `node 6.2.2` and it works fine.

Comment: `package.json` added above, thanks. This app is generated from `ionic start theWhoZoo --v2`, I have not made any changes.

Comment: Thanks, but if I ran `ionic start theWhoZoo --v2` with `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` installed at the time, why is it `"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3"`?  If I want to keep `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`, do I need to change this too? p.s. I don't want to upgrade Ionic (I want to keep it `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`), because I have an existing app in Windows on this version I am trying to build for ios.

Comment: I will copy the Existing apps package.json and see if that works. I just wanted to get a simple app working first, because if I try just run the existing app on OSX, I get this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971497/meteor-ionic-serve-on-windows-vs-osx

Comment: When I run the existing app build in Windows on OSX, I get the same error. `Couldn't find ionic.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?`

Comment: what is the package.json of your existing app?

Comment: I can send you existing apps `package.json`. However, this gets the same error as a vanilla app generated by `ionic start.` The first prolem I see is that an Ionic generated app doesn't seem to work on OSX for `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130011/discussion-between-suraj-rao-and-richard).